# How to simplify the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k q^k(1-p-q)^{n-k}$?

Tags: summation, binomial-theorem

I am trying to simplify the following sum:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k q^k(1-p-q)^{n-k}.$$
There are no specifications on $p$ and $q$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem

Answer (score 3):

By the Binonmial Theorem, $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom n k q^k(1-p-q)^{n-k}
=(q+(1-p-q))^n=(1-p)^n.$$